# What's the meaning of "go to ruins"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Consider this statement:

> Unfortunately, the 2nd business; agent who did the lease of the premise AND the shopping center lied about their plans (said there is a plan development which would put my health club in the forefront of the center instead of at the back) and now, I am watching my finances **go to ruins**.. I am not able to take legal actions as they were very careful not to have anything in writing, mainly verbals and meetings showing me their maps etc.

What's the meaning of *go to ruins*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If something is in ruins, that means it is destroyed.  Imagine a wall that is half on the ground and half standing, a fireplace with the hearth completely destroyed, a roof in a million pieces -- such is a house in ruins.  If something *goes to ruins*, it means that it is destroyed.  *Go to ruins* does not need to be physical, though.  In this case, his finances went to ruins.  The definition of *ruin* from [thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ruin):

> 1. often **ruins**
>      **a**. The state of being physically destroyed, collapsed, or decayed: *The castle fell into ruin*.
>      **b**. The state of being extensively harmed or damaged: *Our vacation plans are in ruins*.
>      **c**. Poverty of bankruptcy: *Their decision brought the bank to ruin*.

Answer (score 0):

[Definition 5](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/ruin_2)

**fall into ruin**  also    **go to ruin**

if something goes to ruin, it gets damaged or destroyed because no one is taking care of it:

> He had let the farm go to ruin.